# Infinitely tetrating zero?

Tags: arithmetic

Although ${0^0}$ is not necessarily defined as $1$, it is often defined that way, with reasons provided as to why. Assume, then, that it is $1$. What would the value of ${0^{0^{0...}}}$ be? (Please forgive me if the answer is just, "There is no [yet?] provable answer." I know that in tetration, you evaluate downward, so ${0^{0^0}}$ would evaluate to ${0^1}$, which would then evaluate to $0$. If you had a neverending such sequence, though, would you end up with two answers, maybe? Like, if you take the infinite sequence pairwise, each pair collapses to 1, and the resulting infinite tetration of $1$ goes to $1$. But IDK because I don't know enough about how similar (similar enough!) questions are decided, so it appears to me you could have a downward evaluation of an infinite tower that kept fluctuating between $0$ and $1$ per pair, maybe even terminating at $0$. Based on a (hazy) recollection of Conway and Guy's *The Book of Numbers* re: $\omega$ (how to characterize odd and even numbers using $\omega$), I suppose that maybe you'd say the tower would collapse to $0$ if there were $\omega+1$ steps (the extra step rendering the final computation incapable of being done pairwise without remainder)? (I'm just shooting in the dark here.)

I tried to find more about this stuff elsewhere beforehand, but didn't come up with anything. Apologies if there's some essay or book out there that I should know about already, that goes over this question.

Comment: $0^0$ is simply undefined. Whenever we let $0^0=1$, it is usually a matter of notational convenience or common understanding than anything else.

Comment: The sequence $0,1,0,1,...$ has no limit at infinity - there's nothing mysterious about it.

Comment: I'd second Noah's comment. The power function is tangential to the point here. We have a sequence defined by $a_{n+1}=\begin{cases}1,&a_n=0\\0,&a_n=1\end{cases}$ and $a_0=0$. In which case, $\big(a_n\big)=0,1,0,1,\ldots$. You could call the limit undefined or call it $\frac12$ with some generalised notion of convergence but I don't think there is any interesting structure to the sequence.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9205211.pdf includes a good argument for why $0^0$ is 1, something more than mere convenience or common understanding. But in any event I simply had the equation as an assumption in the OP, so the extra comment to that effect is not necessary.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer That's false. $0^0 = 1$ in ordinal and cardinal arithmetic. Furthermore it's the empty product, and therefore the identity element under multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Whether $0^0$ is defined or not does not really matter.  The only real numbers for which the infinite tetration converges have a strictly positive lower bound ($e^{-e}$) or else the specific value $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

https://thatsmaths.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/powertowerlambert.pdf appears to provide the answer to my question: "[For] $0 < x < exp(−e)$, it does not converge, but is found to alternate between two values." Or https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.05559.pdf (pg. 17) appears to say (if I'm reading it right) that for $0$, the infinite power tower function has fixed-point values of $0$ or $1$.

EDIT: https://math.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/05/climbing-the-ladder-of-hyper-operators-tetration/ gives the "$1$ if even, $0$ if odd," result.